# Is there a simple shopping cart I can add to my existing website?

Tags: php, ecommerce, shopping-cart

I created a website for my wife, who knits scarves. The site simply displays the 18 different colours she has created, with a Lightbox-like large photo available when clicked.

She would now like to give visitors the option to purchase online and pay with PayPal and possibly Google Checkout.

We do not need a full ecommerce solution; I've looked at several and they all seem to be overkill for our requirements. We don't even need categories. "All" I want is something that will add products to a cart, take the customer details and integrate the payment provider.

So far, the best solution I have found seems to be [this script on Codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/simple-php-shopping-cart/88625) and I wanted to find out if anyone knows of any better products before I commit to this route.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Shameless plug: [Tinycart.com](https://tinycart.com) is simple (copy & paste a `<script>` and then just add some buy links)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a product with options in PayPal which is easy to use and setup.  You just copy and paste their code onto your website and visitors can select the product and colours and add it to their cart. I would go with PayPal over Google Checkout she'll get many more orders with PayPal since more people use it.

http://www.mals-e.com/ is another free option that integrates with PayPal and is copy paste for setup.

Answer (score 1):

We use ECWID and are happy with it

http://www.ecwid.com/